# Adding hreflang to multisite with no plugin?

Tags: multisite, seo

I am developing 3 sites using multisite subdirectories. I've looked at WPML and hreflang manager plugins, but that seems like overkill.

My three sites are all english speaking, just regionally different. What I'd like to achieve is to add the following:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/pagename" hreflang="x-default" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/uk/pagename" hreflang="en-gb" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/au/pagename" hreflang="en-au" />
```

I've played around with `<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>` but am getting bound up. Specifically, I'd like to take the base url (example.com) and then append the multisite and rest of the url (/uk/pagename) like so:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="<?php the_permalink();?>" hreflang="x-default" />
<link rel="alternate" href="<?php echo get_site_url($blog_id == 2); ?>(current pagename)" hreflang="en-gb" />
```

All the pages that exist on the base site, exist on the multisite.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

---

Comment: MultilingualPress does that. Not sure what you mean with overkill. You don’t have to use what you don’t need.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? Were you able to set up MultilingualPress?